# Filter a matrix regarding a certain condition in one column

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, conditional-statements

I have an array that defines an xyz point cloud. Very simply x,y and z with no other fields.

I load this into matlab without issue but now need to filter the z value. I would like to remove rows in the array dependent on preferred values. So for example if z is < than 5 remove this row. I thought the easy way would be to create a new array when finding a row that meets my criteria.

I tried this. Basically run through the whole array and each time I find a row inside my parameters Id like to write it to a new array. So if the first array has 220K columns and I say my new array must conatin z values greater than -5.4 then i should have a new array with less rows.

```
length = size (array, 1)
newarray= []
b=0;
for n = 1:length
  if array(n, 3) > -5.4 %I want to remove anything greater than -5.4 in the %third column
 %newarray = [newarray; array(n)];
  b = b+1
  end
end
```

Very simple but not for me!

Comment: The question has already been answered, but [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/289365) are some people discussing the technique used.

Comment: Your code is not working because you are using linear indices with `array(n)`. To select a row use `array(n,:)`. I recommend to check the documentation for `colon` operator and matrix indexing.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please consider accepting an answer (the one which answered your question best) to indicate the system, that your problem is solved (green check mark on the left).

Answer (score 4):

Simply do:

```
data = [ 1 2 7;
         1 3 3;
         1 2 8 ]

out = data(data(:,3) >= 5,:)
```

which returns

```
data =
     1     2     7
     1     3     3
     1     2     8


out =
     1     2     7
     1     2     8
```

Have a look at that article about [**matrix indexing**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html).

You first need to create a mask, you want the linear index of the rows where the value in the `n`-th column are bigger than `X`

```
mask = data(:,n) > X
```

and then you filter your data with that mask:

```
out = data(mask,:)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the clear instruction and link. Quite embarrassed its so simple...

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand, how your array exactly looks like, but maybe this will help you

```
a=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 1 2 7; 1 2 1; 3 2 1; 4 8 10; 2 3 1; 5 4 48];
a((a(:,3)>6),:) = []
```